# How can i delete from a text file these special characters

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file with special characters that were created during copying from terminal.

Now I would like to remove them.
I tried grep and sed but didn't work maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Special character is an ESC inside a black box, can't copy it but if I do, it turns into a box with numbers inside:

numbers inside that box are:

00

1B

Comment: Is this output from the `script` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can do the job. The process here is simple, we read in all the lines into list while simultaneously replacing the UTF escape character ( which is `\u001b` ), and then print out lines again, but without the escape character. The `< input.txt` sends old text to python command , and `> new_file.txt` sends text to new file.

Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
lines=[l.strip().replace(u"\u001b","") for l in sys.stdin]
print("\n".join(lines))
```

Save it as `delete_escape.py`, make it executable with `chmod +x ./delete_escape.py`, and call it like so:

```
./delete_escape.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I execute this code in a python file or can i do it in terminal?

Comment: @Insanebench420 you can do either, just remember to properly redirect input and output files. Also, please wait a minute - I'm gonna add python script file to the answer

Comment: It gives me an error when i try to execute it. Line 3 its pointing at 1.strip().replace                                                                                                                                     ^

Comment: @Insanebench420 did you copy the script exactly as in the answer ? Copy it to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link plz

Comment: Oh and please include the error too

Comment: ./delete_escape.py < output.txt > rezultat.txt
  File "./delete_escape.py", line 3
    lines=[1.strip().replace(u"\u001b","") for 1 in sys.stdin]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys;
lines=[1.strip().replace(u"\u001b","") for 1 in sys.stdin]
print "\n".join(lines)

Comment: Hope it good enough.

Comment: @Insanebench420 please put it into paste.ubuntu.com and give link here. In the comments, it all becomes squashed and messy

Comment: Also, that's letter l lowercase, not number 1

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23668749/

Comment: I fixed the 1 to l and i got new error   http://paste.ubuntu.com/23668768/

Comment: @Insanebench420  there's still one more number 1 in the file, `for 1 in sys.stdin` Change that one.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23668879/

Comment: @Insanebench420 I edited my script a little. Try that.  Just copy and paste

Comment: I'll update you as soon as i get the time. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `sed`, but you need to use the [ANSI escape](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) in bash to give it the character:

```
sed -i 's/'$'\u001b''//g' file
```

And here it is in action:

[image: screenshot showing the character being removed]

Alternatively, in perl:

```
perl -i -pe 's/'$'\u001b''//g' file
```

And with `tr`:

```
tr -d $'\u001b' < file > newfile
```

Comment: It doesn't delete the ANSI escape inside the .txt file but the output with cat is good. I want it removed from .txt file.

Comment: @Insanebench420 it should. And it does in my tests. If it doesn't, that might be the wrong character. Try creating a file with `printf ':%s:\n' $'\u001b' > file`. That will create a file with the bad character between two `:`. Then, try the command I gave and see if it removes it.

Comment: I tried it out and yes if i make one :u0001b: it will delete it but...             if i make more then that in one line it wont delete it..

Comment: Instead it will delete only the first one and leave the rest.

Comment: @Insanebench420 ah, yes, if you can have more than one you need `g`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it looks like you want to remove the ansi escape sequences present in your text. Try

```
ansifilter file
```

**Update**

To my surprise there is no `ansifilter` package for ubuntu! (there is for fedora, arch, brew, etc)

Nevertheless we can install from [TGZ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ansifilter) or from other packages,
or *wget* the rpm, apply *alien* to build a deb package and install it.

Comment: [No manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=ansifilter), [not provided by any package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ansifilter).

Comment: @muru, you are absolutely right. (I should perhaps remove the answer). There is the TGZ, packages for fedora, centos, arch, brew, ... but not for ubuntu.